# Image not getting displayed when using Reactjs map function. Error--SRC undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image, map-function

Here's the error:

[image]

Everything else gets displayed well instead of my image. I am using image which saved in my local computer and I'm getting no error in VC editor console. I get error in developer tools console.

**./card/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
const Card = (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        return (
        <div className="wrapperDiv">
            <img src={props.img} alt={props.alt}/>
            <p>{props.desc}</p>
            <button>{props.value}</button>
          </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

**./reports/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import Data from './Card/data';

function createCard(Data){
    return <Card
    src={Data.src}
    alt={Data.alt}
    desc={Data.desc}
    value={Data.value}
    />
}


const Reports = () => {
    return (
        <div className="reportsDiv">
           { Data.map(createCard)}
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Reports
```

**data file**

```
import img1 from "./img.jpg";
const Data=[
    {
        id:1,
        img:"{img1}",
        alt:"helloworld",
        desc:"Sdfasdf",
        value:"5GB" 
    },
    {
        id:2,
        img:{img1},
        alt:"helloworld",
        desc:"Sd",
        value:"35GB"
    },
    {
        id:3,
        img:{img1},
        alt:"helloworld",
        desc:"asdf",
        value:"3GB"
    }
]

export default Data;
```

It works if I give value in card component like this:

```
 {/* <Card 
                img={img1}
                alt="helloworld"
                desc="System Junk"
                value="35GB" 
                />
                
                       
                <Card 
                img={img1}
                alt="helloworld"
                desc="Sdfasdf"
                value="35GB" 
                />
                <Card 
                  



img={img1}
                alt="helloworld"
                desc="vhghhjghjg"
                value="35GB" 
                />
               */}
```

But `src` is coming undefined if I use map function. Please help. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note your `createCard` function which you're sending `src` as the image source :

```
function createCard(Data){
    return <Card
    src={Data.src}// you're sending src as the prop
    alt={Data.alt}
    desc={Data.desc}
    value={Data.value}
    />
}
```

But you will use `img` as the source in the `Card` component:

```
const Card = (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        return (
        <div className="wrapperDiv">
            <img src={props.img} // but using img as the prop which is incorrect
                 alt={props.alt}/>
            <p>{props.desc}</p>
            <button>{props.value}</button>
          </div>
    )
}
```

Change the `Card` to the bellow will solve the problem:

```
const Card = (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        return (
        <div className="wrapperDiv">
            <img src={props.src} // change it to src
                 alt={props.alt}/>
            <p>{props.desc}</p>
            <button>{props.value}</button>
          </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi Majid ...Thanks for replying ......i made the change .Also i added key component to my card `function createCard(Data){
     
    
    return <Card
    key={Data.id}
    src={Data.src}
    alt={Data.alt}
    desc={Data.desc}
    value={Data.value}
    />
    
}`..now i am getting this in my  src: {img1: "/static/media/img.f4a2ae0f.jpg"} even though in my import i have path `import img1 from "./img.jpg";`

Comment: You mean it doesn't display the image?

Comment: Yes image still not getting displayed

Comment: What have you get in the `src` of `img` ?

Comment: Hi Majid.... Src: img1: "/static/media/img.f4a2ae0f.jpg"... Where as my image path is img1 from "./img.jpg";

Comment: Instead of importing images in data file, use image's file path based on card component. Because you're using image in the card component not in data file.

Comment: I tried importing in card component. Still image not getting displayed. Also replaced import with` id:1,
        src:require('./img.jpg') ,
        alt:"helloworld",
        desc:"Sdfasdf",
        value:"5GB" 
    } `  then i am getting src: Module {default: "/static/media/img.f4a2ae0f.jpg", __esModule:

Comment: Check your path in comparison of `CardComponent`. I mean if you would like to import the image on `CardComponent`, what will be the source of image? Will it be again './img.jpg'?

Comment: my card component and data file and image all three are in card component folder. I am attaching link to github kindly check the link https://github.com/Nidhi031087/Admin-Dashbard-using-React/tree/main/src/components/Reports/Card

Comment: @fullstackdeveloper the link gives 404 error!

Comment: @fullstackdeveloper Could you please say where is your `CardComponent` in src folder? Also please say that where is your image in src folder?

Comment: https://github.com/Nidhi031087/Admin-Dashbard-using-React/tree/main/src/components/Reports/Card

Comment: src/components/Reports/Card/

Comment: And where is your image?

Comment: all three file in this path : data.js,index,jss and img.jpg

Comment: Are they in root folder? I mean in `src` folder of  project?

Comment: https://github.com/Nidhi031087/newadmin/tree/main/src/components/Reports/Card     kindly check if link is showing now

Comment: looking forward to get solution....thanks for trying to help out

Comment: @fullstackdeveloper  in your  data.js file, change all the img prop in your data model to src. please see this link : https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-kapitsa-w7opw everything works fine.

Comment: Hi i downloaded edited code on codesandbox and try to run on my local computer images are still not there....why its not working on my system

Comment: thanks for working solution on codesandbox

Comment: Have you tried `npm run build` command before you start the app?

Comment: ok , now after running build before npm start again images are not getting displayed. When i trace the path  D:\react\mytrailprojects\admin\src\images physically i can see required image in build too. Its just  not getting displayed.

Comment: I've seen that you have some images in other folders. Please remove all of them and just keep the one in public folder. Same as this structure in this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-star-0rpep

Comment: I think the remote connection in your real code and check the issue will be the final solution. Please leave a comment for contact information.

Comment: i am not able to understand what you are saying in above comment

Comment: @fullstackdeveloper I said that we can make a remote connection and access your code via AnyDesk or TeamViewer ... to see that what is happening. I think it's the final solution. If you would like, please share your contact information for instance telephone number or email to make contact.

Comment: Hi my email id is nidhi.sharma0310@gmail.com.Will send TeamViewer details on mail.

Comment: @fullstackdeveloper I will send email to you. I think it's a good idea if someone investigate your problem for over than 2 weeks, accept his answer! :)

Comment: i am just new to this stack overflow ..pardon me ....i have to click up mark on all the answers???

Comment: @fullstackdeveloper no problem my friend. We are here to learn. Next to my answer there is a tick. If one answer have solved your problem, You can click on the tick to make it green and accept it as the correct answer for further users. Also you can click up to the upvote to make it acceptable.

Comment: @fullstackdeveloper Thank you my friend. I have sent an email for you. Please stay in connect to check your problem.

Comment: The problem was finally solved by Majid (amazing commitment  to solving problem) by coming on  TeamViewer and inspecting the problem where  img={img1} needs to be turned into img=img1.